# how can i make a foreach loop to stop and wait for a click then continue?

Tags: javascript, foreach

```
const arr = [object, object, object, object, object]

arr.forEach(x => {
     object.proterty = myFunction();
})

function myFunction() {
  //click something
  //return what you click;
}
```

my code looks like this, the forEach loop it doesnt wait for the return value from myFunction

Comment: and yes, i have tried async await

Comment: 1) What is `object.proterty`? Your callback argument is `x`. 2) What are you clicking on - you've not assigned any DOM elements to anything.

Comment: Why use a forEach loop at all?

Comment: This code does not shoe you trying what you are asking about. Please [edit] this and show the code where you actually try to implement the solution and show us the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap it in a `promise` and than use `async/await`

like this

```
const arr = [object, object, object, object, object]

arr.forEach(x => {
     object.proterty = myFunction();
})

function myFunction() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
     //click something
    const clickedItem = .... 
    //resolve what you click;
    resolve(clickedItem)

  })
  }
```

Comment: i have tried using async await and still does the same

Answer (score 0):

I think a forEach loop is not what you want. A forEach loop is designed to iterate over an Array one time for each element. There is no way to pause a loop besides with throwing an exception.

If you want something like this maybe take a look in the following methods:

```
Array.prototype.every()
Array.prototype.some()
Array.prototype.find()
Array.prototype.findIndex()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach